# What are the max and min numbers a short type can store in C?

Tags: c, memory, types, short

I'm having a hard time grasping data types in C. I'm going through a C book and one of the challenges asks what the maximum and minimum number a `short` can store.

Using `sizeof(short);` I can see that a short consumes 2 bytes. That means it's 16 bits, which means two numbers since it takes 8 bits to store the binary representation of a number. For example, 9 would be `00111001` which fills up one bit. So would it not be 0 to 99 for unsigned, and -9 to 9 signed?

I know I'm wrong, but I'm not sure why. It says [here](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/CONCEPT/data_types.html) the maximum is (-)32,767 for signed, and 65,535 for unsigned.

> short int, 2 Bytes, 16 Bits, -32,768 -> +32,767 Range (16kb)

Comment: 16-bit means that you have 16 switches that you can turn on and off. The total number of different on-off patterns is 2^16, which is 65536 different states.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are the allowed ranges by the standard?

Comment: @Antimony see the link in Richard J. Ross III's answer: {SHRT_MAX}
 Maximum value of type short.
 Minimum Acceptable Value: +32 767

Comment: remember even though 65536 = 2^16, as per limits.h max limit is 65535 because 65536 is considered as an overflow

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Think in decimal for a second. If you have only 2 digits for a number, that means you can store from `00` to `99` in them. If you have 4 digits, that range becomes `0000` to `9999`.

A binary number is similar to decimal, except the digits can be only `0` and `1`, instead of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `9`.

If you have a number like this:

```
01011101
```

This is:

```
0*128 + 1*64 + 0*32 + 1*16 + 1*8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 1*1 = 93
```

So as you can see, you can store bigger values than `9` in one byte. In an unsigned 8-bit number, you can actually store values from `00000000` to `11111111`, which is 255 in decimal.

In a 2-byte number, this range becomes from `00000000 00000000` to `11111111 11111111` which happens to be 65535.

Your statement "it takes 8 bits to store the binary representation of a number" is like saying "it takes 8 digits to store the decimal representation of a number", which is not correct. For example the number 12345678901234567890 has more than 8 digits. In the same way, you cannot fit *all* numbers in 8 bits, but only 256 of them. That's why you get 2-byte (`short`), 4-byte (`int`) and 8-byte (`long long`) numbers. In truth, if you need even higher range of numbers, you would need to use a library.

As long as negative numbers are concerned, in a 2's-complement computer, they are just a convention to use the higher half of the range as negative values. This means the numbers that have a `1` on the left side are considered negative.

Nevertheless, these numbers are [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) modulo 256 (modulo `2^n` if `n` bits) to their positive value as the number really suggests. For example the number `11111111` is 255 if unsigned, and `-1` if signed which are congruent modulo 256.

Comment: Ok! Thank you. I got it. I have to think in "base-2" numbers instead of base-10. Makes sense now. My understand was way off!

Comment: @Mohamad, exactly. It's fairly similar to base-10. Whenever you get confused, you can use this analogy to understand better ;)

Answer (score 11):

The reference you read is correct.  At least, for the usual C implementations where `short` is 16 bits - that's not actually fixed in the standard.

16 bits can hold 2^16 possible bit patterns, that's 65536 possibilities.  Signed shorts are -32768 to 32767, unsigned shorts are 0 to 65535.

Comment: But it takes 8 bits to store a number, right? The 16 bits can store 2 numbers? I'm missing something here!

Comment: @Mohamad one bit is enough to store a number in range [0;1]. Two bits can store 4 numbers. And so on …

Comment: @Mohamad: No. 8 bits only stores numbers in the range 0-255. 16 bits stores numbers in the range 0-25535. 32-bit (usually `int`) can store somewhere in the 4 billions. You get the idea. It's all powers of two.

Answer (score 9):

This is defined in [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html), and is `SHRT_MIN` & `SHRT_MAX`.

Comment: The OP clearly has problems with understanding binary numbers. How is _this_ going to help him understand?

Comment: @Shahbaz: It's not going to make him understand, but it does give him some simple decimal numbers. `<limits.h>` can also be a very valuable tool when writing portable programs, and who knows if that was the question at the heart of the issue? This question has just the right balance of theory and practicality in it's answers.

Answer (score 3):

Others have posted pretty good solutions for you, but I don't think they have followed your thinking and explained where you were wrong. I will try.

> I can see that a short consumes 2 bytes. That means it's 16 bits,

Up to this point you are correct (though `short` is not guaranteed to be 2 bytes long like `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 — the only guaranteed size by standard (if I remember correctly) is `char` which should always be 1 byte wide).

> which means two numbers since it takes 8 bits to store the binary representation of a number.

From here you started to drift a bit. It doesn't really take 8 bits to store a number. Depending on a number, it may take 16, 32 64 or even more bits to store it. Dividing your 16 bits into 2 is wrong. If not a CPU implementation specifics, we could have had, for example, 2 bit numbers. In that case, those two bits could store values like:

```
00 - 0 in decimal
01 - 1 in decimal
10 - 2 in decimal
11 - 3 in decimal
```

To store 4, we need 3 bits. And so the value would "not fit" causing an overflow. Same applies to 16-bit number. For example, say we have unsigned "255" in decimal stored in 16-bits, the binary representation would be `0000000011111111`. When you add 1 to that number, it becomes `0000000100000000` (256 in decimal). So if you had only 8 bits, it would overflow and become 0 because the most significant bit would have been discarded.

Now, the maximum unsigned number you can in 16 bits memory is — `1111111111111111`, which is 65535 in decimal. In other words, for unsigned numbers - set all bits to 1 and that will yield you the maximum possible value.

For signed numbers, however, the most significant bit represents a sign — 0 for positive and 1 for negative. For negative, the maximum value is `1000000000000000`, which is -32678 in base 10. The rules for signed binary representation are well described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations).

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for that awesome explanation. I can't choose between you and Shahbaz, although props for following my line of thought!

Comment: You are welcome! I was puzzled by these things myself :) Everything is in base 10 :-D

Answer (score 1):

The formula to find the range of any unsigned binary represented number:

```
2 ^ (sizeof(type)*8)
```

Comment: `<<` is the shift left operator. If you shift a 1 bit n bits left, you get 2 to the power of n. `^` means bitwise xor in C.

Comment: @Kay: Thanks. I didn't know a power of two could be just a left shift. Comment +1?

Comment: This is not correct. Integers in C may have padding.

Comment: @2501: Not correct for a theoretical computer, or not correct for the C standard?

Comment: C Standard permits padding bits in integers. You don't need a theoretical computer to show this, it happens on modern architectures for at least one type.